# Selenium in mac

Tags: macos, selenium

I am trying to run Selenium webdriver codes in Mac. But getting the below warning.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

```
package pt;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.*;
import org.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;

public class checknavnode {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ System.setProperty
("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";  
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: Its just warning to make you aware about security

Comment: thanks Rahul, so the code will run without interruption even if I add more steps to it.

Comment: Yes it should work provided there are no other issues.